# грамматика русского языка

Tags: грамотная-речь

*В тарелке* или *на тарелке*? Есть разница?

Comment: Разница есть та же, что и в глубине этих тарелок.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**В тарелке** (внутри тарелки, тарелка мыслится как объём): Он лениво ковырялся в тарелке. Душистая уха дымилась в тарелке.

**На тарелке** (тарелка мыслится как плоскость): На тарелке два яблока. Бутерброды разложили на тарелке.

Иногда могут использоваться оба варианта: "Смял и оставил в тарелке (на тарелке) бумажку с номером ее нового мобильника".

Answer (score 5):

Тарелки бывают мелкие и глубокие. Суп подают в тарелке, а жаркое - на тарелке. Аналогично обстоит со стульями и креслами, на которых и в которых сидят.